# window.location.href does not redirect to a different domain

Tags: javascript, redirect

I'm using XAMPP, and I have two directories in htdocs. Basically, I am trying to do the following:

A button from `localhost/folder-website1 directs` me to `localhost/folder-website2`

If it's any helpful, website2 is a Lumen project that serves as an API, and I'm trying to see if I'm able to connect to it.

Edit:

In website1, I have a button that does the following:

```
function test(){
    window.location.href = "localhost/website2/public";
}
```

From what I see, the URL becomes

```
http://localhost/website1/localhost/website2/public
```

Comment: You forgot the protocol: `window.location.href = "http://localhost/website2/public";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a relative link because the <del>protocol</del> scheme is missing as the beginning of your [URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax). `localhost/website2/public` will redirect to the `localhost/website2/public` URL in the current driectory.

Provide an absolute URL with the schema in order to get to the right page:

```
function test(){
    window.location.href = "http://localhost/website2/public";
}
```

Comment: Yup, saw your comment on my post. Thanks alot, it works now!

Comment: Hi @kot09 if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

use window.location.href = "http://localhost/..."
or use

Thanks
Raj

Comment: It works now, thank you!